# Setting the initial value of a jQuery slider bar to 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The below code creates a jQuery sliderbar which I use in my Python/Django survey  website. The issue is that the initial value is not being set correctly.

`value: 0` seems to just control the position of the slider when the page is loaded, indeed no value is shown in the `$("#slider-result")` when the page is loaded. This should be showing a 0.

So if `value: 0` does not set the initial value to `0`, how do I do this?

The problem is that if a user submits the survyform without moving the slider then no value, not even a `0` is recorded.

**slider_two.js**

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var username = $('#hidden').val();
    if (username == "") username = 0;  
    $.post('comment.php', {
        hidden: username
    }, function(return_data) {
        alert(return_data);
    });
});

$(".slider").slider({
    animate: true,
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: -100,
    max: +100,
    step: 1,



//This updates the slider-result below the slider bar so the participant can see the rating they give
    slide: function(event, ui) { 
      $("#slider-result").html((ui.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + ui.value);



//This updates the hidden form field so I can submit the data using a form
      if($(this).attr("id") ==  "one")
          $("#hidden1").val((ui.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + ui.value);
    }
});
```

## EDIT

I added the suggested solution directly to my template just above the `slider-result` but it does not seem to make a difference. Am I missing something?

Deleted history and forced all files to reload with `Command Shift R`

Thanks

```
<script>
    ($function(){
        $("#slider-result").html('0');
        $("#hidden1").val('0');
    });
</script>




<div id="slider-result"></div>                                  

<input type="hidden" name="slider_value" id="hidden1"/>     

          <script src="/static/survey/js/slider_two.js"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the value on page load, the setting applies to the slider itself not the element and if it's not declared anywhere it won't have any value. Either in jquery:

```
($function(){
    $("#slider-result").html('0');
    $("#hidden1").val('0');
});
```

Or event better directly in your template, so no processing on client side:

```
<div id="slider-result">0</div>                                  

<input type="hidden" name="slider_value" id="hidden1" value="0"/>     

          <script src="/static/survey/js/slider_two.js"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Julien, I added your solution to the template, see my EDIT with no result. Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: see edit, I think you're better setting it in your html directly. Is there any reason why it would be better dynamically?

Comment: That Sir is simplicity itself. I never even thought of it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that defaultValue is **not implemented** for hidden form fields. So you have two options of how to solve this.

1. Set the value on page load using javascript as Julien has said above.
2. Use an text input field with value=0 and CSS set to dispaly:none